# Macro to copy a worksheet and paste into a new file using paste special values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro and I want it to copy sheet 1 from file A, and paste it (using paste special values) into file B, and hide the macro button on the pasted sheet in file B? This is my starting point

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

Sheets("Dallas").Select
Sheets("Dallas").Copy

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try to record a macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking only to copy cell values and nothing else, a shortcut would be something like:

```
dim rgSource as range
dim rgTarget as range

set rgSource = ActiveSheet.UsedRange  ' cells containing values on src sheet
set rgTarget = Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1) ' new range on target sheet
set rgTarget = rgTarget.Resize(rgSource.Rows.Count, rgSource.Columns.Count) ' same sz

rgTarget = rgSource.Value  ' copies values into the target range on the other sheet
```

Comment: you could add the following stmt ==> rgTarget.NumberFormat = "0.00"